# Create Outlook task with Java

Tags: java, .net, com, outlook, exchange-server

I have a requirement to have a new task appear in a user's task list in Outlook. The catch is that the source of the task will be generated in a Java environment. Does anyone know how I can create an Outlook task using Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Exchange Web Services SDK - basically a SOAP web service you can call.

[Creating a task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563029%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx), scroll down past the .net code for the xml that is sent to the server.